# Split int array into two arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm

So I'm trying to split int array into two arrays that the difference of arrays sums would be minimum. Does anyone have any ideas how can I do that? Or any tips?

F.e.
`int[] S = { 1, 1, 3, 6 };`

We can split `S` array into

```
int[] a = {1,1,3};
```

and

`int[] b = {6};`

Array `a` sum is 5 and array `b` sum is 6 so the minimum difference is 1. By the way, I'm trying to get split arrays of `S` like `a` and `b`, not the sums difference.

Input:
`int[] S = { 1, 1, 3, 6 };`

Output: `int[] a = {1,1,3};` and `int[] b = {6};`. That's what I'm trying to do.

So far I've tried [Link](http://www.techiedelight.com/minimum-sum-partition-problem/)

**PROBLEM SOLVED! Thank you everyone for help!**

Comment: on what condition do you want to split the array ?

Comment: What would be the condition for split? How about the output if the array is `{2,3,4,5,7,7,8,9}`. And what you have tried so far?>

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier that the difference of subset sums would be minimum

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems to be a simple exercise in array traversing...

Comment: The programming part is trivial. It is a math problem.

Comment: Build every possible combination of array splits, then pick the one with the smallest difference between the two.

Comment: @ElmoDev001 If the elements of the subarray can't be reordered, then even the math problem is trivial.

Comment: @xanatos: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](http://www.techiedelight.com/minimum-sum-partition-problem/) you gave is for a more complex problem than the one you are showing us. In your example, elements can't be "reordered", so you can only subdivide the array in two parts. You simply have to choose where to "cut".

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 6 };

int leftSum = 0;
int rightSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    rightSum += array[i];
}

int leftArraySize = 0;
int minDiff = rightSum;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    rightSum -= array[i];
    leftSum += array[i];

    int diff = Math.Abs(rightSum - leftSum);

    if (diff < minDiff)
    {
        minDiff = diff;
        leftArraySize = i + 1;
    }
}

var leftArray = new int[leftArraySize];
var rightArray = new int[array.Length - leftArraySize];
Array.Copy(array, 0, leftArray, 0, leftArray.Length);
Array.Copy(array, leftArray.Length, rightArray, 0, rightArray.Length);
```

Simple code, without Linq: you have two "sum pools", `leftSum` and `rightSum`. You sum all the elements of the array in the `rightSum` pool. Then element by element you "move" one element from the `rightSum` sum to the `leftSum` sum. You then check if/when the difference between two "sum pools" is the minimum one. Then you simply copy the elements in two new arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        int minIndex = -1;
        int minDiff = int.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            int p1 = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                p1 += values[j];

            int p2 = 0;

            for (int k = i + 1; k < values.Length; k++)
                p2 += values[k];

            int diff = Math.Abs(p1 - p2);

            if (diff < minDiff)
            {
                minIndex = i;
                minDiff = diff;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Min index = " + minIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("Min difference = " + minDiff);
```

Comment: *Inner loops* `for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) { ...for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {` make your solution *inefficient* in case of **large** arrays: e.g. `values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToArray();`

Comment: You are right, I did not consider the performance.

Comment: Okay. I understand what this code does. But what if `values` array would be `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15 };`? The output is `Min difference = 6` and `Min index = 4`. I can split this array into `{15, 3}` and `{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}`(and now min difference is 0). I'm trying to split array that the sums difference would be minimum.

Comment: We are assuming you can't reorder the array, but just split it in one point.